# cannot read data of undefined? json

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, kendo-mvvm

here is my code to save values using js

```
 self.Save = function (e) {

    if (vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencyName == null) {
          alert("Fill Some Thing");
    }
    if (vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencyCode != null) {
        debugger;

        var text1 = { "CurrencyCode": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencyCode, "CurrencyName": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencyName, "CurrencySign": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencySign, "DecimalPlaces": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.DecimalPlaces, "PositiveFormat": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.PositiveFormat, "NegativeFormat": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.NegativeFormat, "CurrencyStatus": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencyStatus };
        self.dsProduct.add(text1);
       ///////////error comes here while i call sync()
        self.dsProduct.sync();
     ////cannot read data of undefined
    }
    if (e.data.CurrencyName != null) {
        debugger;
        var text2 = { "CurrencyName": e.data.CurrencyName, "CurrencySign": e.data.CurrencySign, "DecimalPlaces": e.data.DecimalPlaces, "PositiveFormat": e.data.PositiveFormat, "NegativeFormat": e.data.NegativeFormat, "CurrencyStatus": e.data.CurrencyStatus };
        self.dsProduct.add(text2);
      /////////sucess
        self.dsProduct.sync();
      /////sucess
    }

}
```

text2 works but text1 does not works when i sent values top controller to save durring debuuging i check format boths format was same what should i do to sync the values so that server side receives them for updation

here is the format in console debug for both text1 and text2

```
   CurrencyCode: 20
   CurrencyName: "dollar"
   CurrencySign: "$"
   CurrencyStatus: "23"
   DecimalPlaces: 1
   NegativeFormat: "12"
   PositiveFormat: "12"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       self.Save = function (e) {
                    debugger;
                    if (vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencyCode == null)
                    {
                        var GetValuesForSaving = { "CurrencyName": e.data.CurrencyName, "CurrencySign": e.data.CurrencySign, "DecimalPlaces": e.data.DecimalPlaces, "PositiveFormat": e.data.PositiveFormat, "NegativeFormat": e.data.NegativeFormat, "CurrencyStatus": e.data.CurrencyStatus };
                    self.dsProduct.add(GetValuesForSaving);
                    self.dsProduct.sync();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        debugger;
                        var GetValuesForSaving = { "CurrencyC": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencyCode, "CurrencyName": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencyName, "CurrencySign": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencySign, "DecimalPlaces": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.DecimalPlaces, "PositiveFormat": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.PositiveFormat, "NegativeFormat": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.NegativeFormat, "CurrencyStatus": vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencyStatus };
                        self.dsProduct.add(GetValuesForSaving);
                    self.dsProduct.sync();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking to you code  only thing comes to mind is that in vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencyCode is "undefined".

YOu can user browser debugger to check the value at runtime. And also try this

```
if(vm_Currencies.selectedRow.CurrencyCode != "undefined")
{
//Code Here
}
```

another option

```
if(vm_Currencies != "undefined")
{
//Code here
}
```

Comment: the code is perfect i get currency code value even i have edited question now check the comments

Comment: why this is not aceepting currency code their is only a problem with that